# Reporting Services SubReport only works first time

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

Well, this is weird:

**My server:** SharePoint 2013 Enterprise farm with SRSS up & running & several simple reports working.
**My development environment:** Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Pro with SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio

**The Problem:**
I am designing a "MainReport" with several datetime parameters, containing a tablix, and I need to display in a cell the value of a field that is in another list.

- My main list is called "Documentation"
- It has a lookup field that
  references a "Document Set" library called "Contents".
- I need to obtain a ***metadata*** field value from the document set list.

**My approach:** To achieve this I've created another report called "SubReport" who has a query that filters the items by ID (received as a parameter) and shows the right value in a textbox.

*I can run this "SubReport" alone anytime I want to.*

Then I've added this "SubReport" inside a cell of "MainReport"'s tablix, configured all the properties, and using the expression editor I'm sending the current row ID as a parameter.

**Question:** What's weird?

**Answer:** It only works the first time you run the main report, if I do a refresh or try to filter again the report it shows "#Error" inside the cell instead of the "SubReport" right value.

This means that if I come back to design the "MainReport", remove the "SubReport", and add it all again, the report will show the right output again.

**Solution:** You tell me, please.